# Warning: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in <file> on line <number>

Tags: php, mysqli

The view file

```
<?php

require('OrderModel.php');

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['orderModel'])){
    $newModel = new OrderModel();
    $_SESSION['orderModel'] = $newModel;
} else{
    $newModel = $_SESSION['orderModel'];
}

$newModel->addToBasket(1, 30);
echo $newModel->getItemName($newModel->basket[0][0]);
?>
```

The OrderModel file (simplified)

```
class OrderModel{

public $basket;
public $orderDate;
public $orderTime;
public $sent;
public $dbc;
public $customerOrderID;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->dbc = require_once('../../db/config.php');
    $this->basket = [];
}

public function addToBasket($itemNumber, $itemQuantity){
    array_push($this->basket, [$itemNumber, $itemQuantity]);
}

public function getItemName($itemNum){
    $query = "SELECT ItemName FROM item WHERE ItemID = $itemNum;";
    $r = mysqli_query($this->dbc, $query); //Line 31
    if($r){
        return mysqli_fetch_row($r)[0];
    }else{
        echo mysqli_error($this->dbc); //Line 35
    }
}
```

I can confirm that the config.php file is **definitely** configured correctly and is talking to the DB. In any rate, the code is:

```
<?php
define ('username', 'root');
define ('password', 'root');
define ('server', '127.0.0.1');
define ('database', 'alberto');

$dbc = mysqli_connect(server, username, password, database) OR DIE ('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());

mysqli_set_charset($dbc, 'utf8');

return $dbc;
?>
```

I am getting the following error messages from the view file:

Warning: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in D:\UniServerZ\www\alberto\app\models\OrderModel.php on line 31

Warning: mysqli_error(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in D:\UniServerZ\www\alberto\app\models\OrderModel.php on line 35

I suspect the error is to do with the session, but I can't seem to find any answers from the threads posted so far.

Please kindly advise. Thank you.

Comment: What does `var_dump($this->dbc)` show?

Comment: The error means that `$this->dbc` is not a valid `mysqli` object.

Comment: Do you have `require_once('../../db/config.php')` somewhere else in the script? Since you use `require_once`, only the first one will be executed. Use `require` instead of `require_once`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Barmar is correct that $this->dbc is not a valid mysqli object. You are using the require_once with the file like a function. Make the config.php a class, and make the db connection from there. See here for an example of what I'm referring to. https://gist.github.com/jonashansen229/4534794

Comment: Thank you, I see what you mean. A somewhat related question: Does the db info ($dbc = ...) need to be required in every single file? If so, what will be the definition of "every single file"?

Comment: Excellent question! Yes and no. Yes, the database connection needs to be available anytime you need to make a query. How you do it is where the 'no' comes in. Personally, I like to use a psr-4 autoloader to map out the classes and make them available on a case by case basis. For now, what you can do is have a 'main' require file that includes all your critical classes like session management and dbconnections, and then require that 'main' file.

Comment: The reason I asked is that I have done a hack job. In my view file, I have:

    <?php
    require_once ('db/config.php');
    require_once('app/models/OrderModel.php');
    require_once ('app/controllers/OrderController.php');

In my model file, I "cheated" by doing this:
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->dbc = $GLOBALS['dbc'];